# How to update URL in a URL textfield in xcode using WKWebkit when any website is loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to update URL in a textfield in Xcode using WKWebkit when any website is selected. In case of WebView we do like this :-

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
{
    NSURL *requestURL       = [webView.request URL];
    _txtAddress.text   = [requestURL absoluteString];
}
```

But how to do in `WkWebkit` i don't know ?

Answer (score 0):

> WKWebKit has its own navigationDelegate and you can implement that
>   protocol to do the same things

here is the one for the [didFinishNavigation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKNavigationDelegate/webView:didFinishNavigation:) which you can use.

Comment: I used Like this but still it showing error undeclared identifier webKit- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
{
    NSURL *requestURL       = [webView.request URL];
    _txtAddress.text   = [requestURL absoluteString];
}